# Ionic\Cordova : Displaying icons of installed applications (ANDROID)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to develop a Launcher like application using Ionic + Cordova.
I have used the [AppList](https://github.com/michael79bxl/cordova-plugin-applist) plugin and it works well. However I can't get the icon paths it returns to display in my html templates, they just appear as empty `<img/>`. Is it even possible to display icons from `/data/data/my_app` in my templates ? If not, is there another way \ plugin to achieve my goal ?

Comment: i know at least 2 ways to do that: 1) convert on native side images to `base64` strings, 2) store images in other place and load them from javascript. 1st way is good one, because you don't have big images